# Python: method to extract tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, extract

I have a tuple of constants:

`WIN = 640, 360, "Example", False, 'tool' # x, y, title, resizable, style`

And now to use it I have to type in this:

`app = pyglet.window.Window(WIN[0], WIN[1], WIN[2], WIN[3], WIN[4])`

Is there a method to split tuple into separate elements like this:

`app = pyglet.window.Window(WIN.extract())` ?

Comment: have you tried `app = pyglet.window.Window(*WIN)`?

Comment: I tried it now and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app = pyglet.window.Window(*WIN)

Comment: i know it is the same answer as everyone else but i wrote it first as a comment, then as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use star unpacking.

```
app = Window(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
app = pyglet.window.Window(*WIN)
```